# Changing Specific DOM Node PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have the following code:

```
$item = "What I have: <a href='/id/blablabla'>This $oldtext.</a>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($item);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    if(strpos($node->getAttribute('href'),'/id/') !== false) {
         $oldtext = // ?
         $newtext = "This is old:".$oldtext."And this is new: New.";
         // then replace 'This $oldtext.' in $item as $newtext
    }
}
```

This checks if any  nodes in my `$item` have an href containing /id/. If they do, they are supposed to **save the current text, referred to as `$oldtext`** of the node, then **replace the text with new text,** which will use `$oldtext` in the new text.

**EDIT:** I've added what the $item looks like for clarity.

How can I save `$oldtext` even if the node changes, and change the node itself?

Comment: Maybe I dont follow but couldn't you just do $oldtext = $node->getAttribute('href')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant the text node of it, then just simple access the `->nodeValue` property. Just overwrite it like any accessible object property:

```
$item = "What I have: <a href='/id/blablabla'>This \$oldtext.</a>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($item);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    if(strpos($node->getAttribute('href'),'/id/') !== false) {
         $oldtext = $node->nodeValue;
         $node->nodeValue = "This is old:".$oldtext."And this is new: New.";
         // then replace 'This $oldtext.' in $item as $newtext
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/s3qujv)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is, to replace the text using    `$node->setAttribute('href', $newtext);` and then save the HTML at the end by doing: `$dom->saveHTML();`

See complete example below:

```
    $item = "What I have: <a href='/id/blablabla'>This $oldtext.</a>";
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($item);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
        if(strpos($node->getAttribute('href'),'/id/') !== false) {
             $oldtext = // ?
             $newtext = "This is old:".$oldtext."And this is new: New.";
             // then replace 'This $oldtext.' in $item as $newtext
            $node->setAttribute('href', $newtext);
        }
    }

   $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This is moving in the right direction, but you are targeting the wrong thing. Basically, I need to set the inside of the <a> tag to $newtext, not the href associated with it.